# Are the positions of the vertical clamps for the fixed shower glass panels adjustable?

Tags: shower, glass

I am in doubt about where to position (at what level) an 1.5" ABS pipe in the wall as the wall will support of fixed shower glass panel, so where you see the question mark in the picture I need to know if that quote is standard (? depending on the manufacturer) or it is adjustable for most of the models

I have tried a couple of suppliers but none of them has technical drawings or videos showing how to install and adjust these

[image]

Comment: I am sure that there is some tolerance for locating the brackets for fixed glass shower enclosure panels. However, what that tolerance is depends on the technical details. I find it **very** hard to believe that the installation instructions and/or technical data sheet doesn't include this specification, which leads me to believe you have not yet actually sourced the glass panel in question. What make and model panel are you installing? No reputable supplier would fail to give you guidance on the bracket location...

Comment: I have not decided on what glass I am going to install; it seems that I will have to decide but that depends on how I am going to position the shower base and I am not there yet (I have a shower base that goes 0.5" under the side of the adjacent cabinet so now I am trying to notch the plate of the frame to get back that 0.5")

Comment: Yes see this one https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/208849/do-i-need-to-plan-my-framing-depending-on-the-position-of-the-wall-to-glass-clam/208869?noredirect=1#comment381811_208869

Comment: @isherwood wow... It seems I hadn't yet had enough coffee when I posted that this morning. Obviously, I read it as the pipe _supporting_ the glass instead of having the pipe _avoiding_ the glass support. Totally my bad!

Comment: no problem it happens

Answer (score 1):

These clamps grip the  edge of the sheet of glass  so they can be installed at any position along the edges of the sheet. The one on the arm at the top edge which you didn't mark is also adjustable.

Be sure position them to give sufficient support to all parts of the sheet.

Use safety glass.

Comment: Is that so for any door, for most of them or for some of them? I cant find amy documentation. Do you have any references you can point me to?

Comment: No one can answer to the level of confidence you seem to be seeking. It's a proprietary and installation-specific thing.

Comment: I would suggest, @MiniMe, that if you're that concerned, that you leave the wall open until you've picked out your shower surround. That way, you can ensure that you've got framing in the proper location for the door you've chosen.

Comment: complex situation I can't do that